# Fast search via index with keeping insertion order in C++

Tags: c++, search, boost, containers, boost-multi-index

I need a container which has ability to search over 1 million items pretty fast and keep the insertion order.

So first I thought about std::map but it doesn’t care about the insertion order it orders the data according to the key. 
An I found boost::multi_index which shall preserve the insertion order and search for the data fast via the indexed field (which is id (*not unique!*) for my case). So I did something like that:

```
struct myData
{
    unsigned long id;
    unsigned long insertionOrder;

    myData (){};
    myData (unsigned long id_,unsigned long insertionOrder_):id(id_), insertionOrder(insertionOrder _)){}
    ~ myData (){};
};


typedef multi_index_container<
    myData, 
        indexed_by<    
            random_access<>,  // keep insertion order
            ordered_non_unique< member< myData, unsigned long, & myData::id> >
        > 
> myDataContainerType;
```

I can push data into the container without any problem. Let’s say I insert 5 item to my container like:

```
myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1002, 1));
myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1001, 2));
myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1005, 3));
myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1003, 4));
myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1000, 5));
```

The problem is when I perform a search in my container for the item `“1001”` the `iterator++` returns `"1002"` and the `iterator—` returns `"1000"`. So it seems that it doesn’t care about the insertion order and orders the data according to the indexed value as well.

I expect results for the `iterator++` : `“1002”` and for `iterator--` :  `“1005”`. I mean the data according to the insertion order.

Am i doing smth wrong? How can I achieve something like doing fast search via the index value and retreiving the data according to the insertion order.

**I am working on Visual Studio 2008, Visual C++, Win 7 x64 computer.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there with your `boost::multi_index` attempt. The problem was that when you did the find using the ordered index, the iteration was *also* being ordered. Luckily the multi-index provides a `project` mechanism to switch between indexes. If I read the documentation correctly:

```
auto ordered_iter = myMap.find(1001);
auto iter = boost::multi_index::project<0>(ordered_iter);
```

Comment: I didn't know that method. I will definitely try this. But the question is does ut work with random_access? Or do i have to implement another orderd_unique index?

Comment: It should work fine with any index types provided by `multi_index`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `multimap<Key,List<Item>::Iterator>` paired with a `List<Item>`.  I would use the map for lookup and the List would hold the items in insertion order.  You will need to keep both containers up to date on all insertion/update/deletion scenarios.  If you could expound on your use case a better option may be available.

This option would give you log(n) lookup while still allow constant time removal of the index and the item. This is similar to how I have implemented LRU caches in the past.

### Edit due to question

```
typedef list<myData> DataLst;
typedef DataLst::iterator LstIter; 
typedef multimap<unsigned long, LstIter> mpType; 

mpType BuildIndex(DataLst &lst)
{
    mpType ret; 
    for (auto Item = begin(lst); Item != end(lst); Item++)
    {       
        ret.insert(make_pair(Item->id,Item));
    }
    return ret; 
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DataLst myDataContainer; 
    myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1002, 1));
    myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1001, 2));
    myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1005, 3));
    myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1003, 4));
    myDataContainer.push_back(myData(1000, 5));

    auto myMap = BuildIndex(myDataContainer);
    auto iter = myMap.find(1001);
    cout << "The iter insert  = " << iter->second->insertionOrder << endl;
    cout << "The iter insert after = " <<  std::next(iter->second)->insertionOrder << endl;
    cout << "The iter insert before = " << std::prev(iter->second)->insertionOrder << endl;
    string foo; 
    cin >> foo; 
}
```

### output

```
The iter insert  = 2
The iter insert after = 3
The iter insert before = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you provide some specific code examples about what you mean?

Comment: If it doesn't work with multi_index i will try that one, thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what Mark B offered is exactly correct. I just wanted to submit the right syntax for the benefit of possible future visitors.

I created a typedef:

```
typedef myDataContainerType::nth_index<1>::type myDataContainerType_by_id;

myDataContainerType myDataContainer;
```

and the syntax for finding the data according to id and changing index to insertion order:

```
myDataContainerType_by_id& idIndex = myContainer.get<1>();
myContainerType_by_id::iterator itId = idIndex.find(fId);

if (itId == idIndex.end())
    return 0;

myDataContainerType::const_iterator itInsertionOrder = myDataContainer.project<0>(itId);

// *** Alternative way to change index which works as well
myDataContainerType::const_iterator itInsertionOrder2 = myDataContainer.iterator_to(*itId);
// ***
```